# php get the result after a function

Tags: php, web-services

I have this code in php that connect with NAV web service.

```
$page = new NTLMSoapClient($pageURL);

//DEFINE THE FILTERS AND FUNCTION TO CALL

$params = array(
    "p_codFreqNo" => "",
    "p_txtFirstName"=> "",
    "p_txtLastName"=> "",
    "p_txtAddress"=> "",
    "p_txtAddress2"=> "",
    "p_txtEmail"=>  "",
    "p_txtPhoneNo"=> "52206804",
    "p_txtBirth"=>  "01/01/1900",
    "p_intGender"=> "1",
    "p_txtMobileNo"=>  "",
    "p_intCreateOrUpdate" => 0
    );
$result = $page->CreateMember($params);
```

Perfect, this is working but this function should return me a result. I am not good in php but I use this code:

```
var_dump($result);
```

And I have got this result:

object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["return_value"]=> string(8) "20000868" }

The number at the end is the result I am looking for. But I need only the number not all the other details.

Any idea about how can I get only the number?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried but I got this Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in D:\Xampp\htdocs\tomas\create.php on line 88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
echo $result->return_value;
```

Comment: Looks like an underscore, not a hyphen.

Comment: I have tried but I got this:   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$return in D:\Xampp\htdocs\tomas\create.php on line 88

Notice: Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' in D:\Xampp\htdocs\tomas\create.php on line 88
0

Comment: ha! i wouldn't say that, but you're welcome. upvote and/or accept if it helped, or not, up to you!

Comment: I am going to put it like the right question but I need to wait 5 minutes